# how to use Whenever gem properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whenever

I am just trying to create a record every 5 minutes using `whenever gem` but it doesn't create anything on the production.

**config/schedule.rb**

```
every 5.minutes do 
 runner "Post.new_post"
end
```

**lib/tasks/post.rb**

```
class Post
  def new_post
    Post.create(title: "cron testing")
  end
end
```

and I ran `whenever` command then pushed to the live server but It doesn't create any records on the production.

Which steps did I miss?

Comment: Did you run `whenever --update-crontab` on production?

Comment: Set your log file with `set :output, "log/cron_log.log"`in schedule.rb file so you can check logs. which error coming

Comment: @Vishal no.. how can I run that command on production?

Comment: Go to production server and directly run this command. `whenever --update-crontab`

Comment: It depends also on your prod environment. What are you using to put your app in production? AWS / GCS / Heroku / something else?

Comment: @bo-oz I am using hatchbox..

Comment: Sorry, not familiair with that solution, did find this, but it isn't helpful at all! https://hatchbox.gitbook.io/hatchbox/apps/cron-jobs. Maybe ask their helpdesk?

Comment: @bo-oz thanks for your help. I found where to put command, which sasys `Bash Script` and I added what @Vishal mentioned `whenever --update-crontab` and when I ran the script, it returns `.hatch/action-164052.sh: line 1: whenever: command not found`.

Comment: I'd try to run `bundle exec whenever --update-crontab` instead... otherwise, please contact support of Hatchbox, as it seems platform specific.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're using rails, so — files placed in lib/tasks are loaded as custom rake tasks by default, you can check it [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks).

Brief instruction:

- Run `rails generate task posts create_post`
- Modify `lib/tasks/posts.rake`
- Update `config/schedule.rb` from
  `runner "Post.new_post"` to `rake 'posts:create_post'`
- Run `whenever --update-crontab` somehow on the server ;)